# NavigationView's color when checked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

Usually, the ItemTextColor and ItemIconTint will change to android:colorPrimary then checked, but why it change to white(the primary color of Theme.AppCompat) instead of my custom primary color?

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<color name="color_primary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="color_primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="color_accent">#FF4081</color>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompat themes uses `colorPrimary` and related attributes without the `android:` prefix. So if you change your style.xml to the following it should work. (Or at least, it's how it works for me.)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<color name="color_primary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="color_primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="color_accent">#FF4081</color>
```